# UFrame not working in jquery-1.6.2

Tags: jquery, uframe

The UFrame works in jquery-1.2.3 but not in jquery-1.6.2

you can get the source here...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/uframe.aspx

i'm having an error in line 513 char 9

w/c is

`enter code here`$('div[@src]',document).each(function()

in file UFrame.js

but when i look into the function... in jquery-1.6.2.js

the function

```
each: function (callback, args) {
                return jQuery.each(this, callback, args);
            }
```

exists too... where did i go wrong?

Comment: I found an answer to error 513 char 9..

i change "div[@src]" to "div[src]" in uframe.js


but now i'm getting error in line 144 char 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery got rid of the '@' prefix for attributes in newer versions.  Just remove every occurrence of '@' from UFrame.js.