# Example for Uframe in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

Thanks in advance.
I tried working with Uframe in my project but its not working for me can anyone please give me a sample how it works

Thanks
Ashok

Comment: Show some code, tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using jQuery 1.2.3 as supplied.

Or you can see this post:
[UFrame not working in jquery-1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303515/uframe-not-working-in-jquery-1-6-2)